# Why would cells overlap each other in UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

my app has tens of tableViews, they all work ok, except one relatively long table that if i add a cell as a final cell, it gets duplicated with this overlapping.

I checked the table source, it has one cell of this type, why it gets duplicated ?

I use this common way to call the cell by name

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellName, forIndexPath: indexPath)
```

after all refreshes, you can see one "reportPlace" id, why all these duplicates.

```
items = [["similarPlace", "similarPlace", "similarPlace", "reportPlace"]]
```

[image]

--

[image: disaster]

> Disclaimer : I checked all mentioned solutions for similar problems

Comment: let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Songcell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

Comment: Can you both your view controller code?

Comment: Check you cell height as per last cell,  if you have taken custom view then

Comment: MichaelRose : it's a 2k lines code, i'm not doing anything unusual, it always works with me in other views, i think this is an xcode bug...

HimanshuMoradiya : i did that already

Comment: Did you check on `Debug View Hierarchy` ?

Comment: @Vahid + others : i did add the exploded view, why this disaster happens ??

Comment: Is the pick section footerView of table ?

Comment: How do you use that cell? Do you manually add subview ? Seems to be a reuse issue for me.

Comment: thanks, I posted the solution as an answer.

Comment: @EricAya noted, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution : determine the height only once.**

I was setting the height of the cell multiple times which it was causing this problem:

```
self.tableView?.rowHeight   = 60.0
self.tableView?.rowHeight   = 100.0
```

I thought it will take the last one, but it looks like each one makes an instance of the cell.

also, don't reload the table more times than needed.
and don't change source data in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: i set `tableview.estimatedRowHeight` in my tableview-prepare-method which made me to struggle with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and could not figure why exactly it happens (the y position was set wrong), but I did a small 'hack' that solved the problem for me

If you are creating the cell programatically just do this in the `init` in the cell class:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
  let noProblemFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: frame.height)
  super.init(frame: noProblemFrame)
}
```

otherwise do the same in `awakeFromNib`

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
   let noProblemFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: frame.height)
   frame = noProblemFrame
```

Comment: thanks, I didn't try this to be honest, what solved it for me is the answer I added.

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the above answers but nothing worked for me except Sandu's answer, that did the trick!

```
// Working solutions, any value will do
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 200
```